# Discord.js ID kick command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I'm making kick command with buttons and embed so i need to get id from the embed.
That is:

```js
interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[0].value.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g,"")
```

This is the code i use to kick member:

```js
client.users.fetch(interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[0].value.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g,"")).then((member) => {
        member.kick()
      })
```

I'm fetching member with ID but, it still dont work and error is:

```
        member.kick()
               ^

TypeError: member.kick is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.users.fetch()` returns a Discord User. Only a GuildMember can be kicked. Use `interaction.guild.members.fetch()` instead.

```js
interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[0].value.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g,"")).then(member => {
   member.kick();
});
```

Comment: thaaanks man <3